# Is $\log|x-y|$ a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, logarithms

I must be missing something... I am currently reading the book by Burago,Burago and Ivanov,  *A Course in Metric Geometry*, in which it was stated that the map $d_{\log}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by $d_{\log}(x, y) = \log|x-y|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems to me that this map is not only undefined for when $ x = y$, but there also seems to be the issue that it returns negative values for when $|x-y| < 1$ and fails the positivity condition for when $y = x + 1$.

I was perhaps thinking that the function would require some redefinition for various pairs $(x,y)$; with this being the case, however, I still find it strange that the authors would go so far as to make that initial claim without any disclaimer. Could anyone help clarify this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are right, $\log|x-y|$ isn't non-negative or finite over $\mathbb R^2$. So it isn't a metric.

Comment: Once you have a metric, perhaps you should ask what properties in general a function needs such that f o d is another metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously not a metric for the reasons you described.

If you're reading the [online version](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/bbi.pdf), the problem lies there -- the [actual book](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-33/18) uses $d_{log}(x,y)=\log(|x-y|+1)$, which is indeed a metric: symmetric, non-negative (and zero iff $x=y$) and you can check the triangle inequality on your own.